# Getting result in an array from a function with while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function in a class called database, the function as below

```
function getTaskData(){ 
    $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_CLIENT ;
    $result = mysqli_query( $this->connection,$q);
    if(!$result || (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1)){
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Return result array */
    ;
    while ($dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        return $dbarray;    
    }
}
```

Please note that $dbarray is from while loop, however, i want to call the function to loop out specific data from the table in a while loop

please see below, i am calling the function from another page

```
$taskData= $database->getTaskData();
$taskStatus = $taskData['status'];
echo $taskStatus
```

I want $taskStatus to be in a loop.

Comment: You either collect all rows to one array and return it from your function, or return `$result` from your function and iterate it where you need.

Comment: @u_mulder  please explain better or give example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your loop in a function with:

```
$results = [];
while ($dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[] = $dbarray;    
}

return $results;
```

Somewhere else:

```
$taskData = $database->getTaskData();
foreach ($taskData as $item) {
    echo $item['status'];
}
```